# matching string using regular expression

Tags: regex, string, match

```
text = "hellovision hey creator   yoyo  b  creator great  publisher"
```

I want to extract creator's name and publisher's name from text.

The result will be,

creator = hellovision hey, yoyo

publisher = great

How can I get text using regular expression?

Do I need to use span()..?

This is my code.

```
def preprocess2(text):

    text_list = test.split(' ')
    lyricist = []
    composer = []
    music_arranger = []
    temp = []
    lyricist.clear()
    composer.clear()
    music_arranger.clear()
    for i in range(0, len(text_list)):
        if text_list[i] == 'creator':
            print(len(text_list))
            for a in range(0, i-1):
                temp.append(text_list[a])
            lyricist.append(''.join(temp))
            temp.clear()
            for b in range(0, i+1):
                print(b)
                text_list.pop(b)
                print(len(text_list))
            break
        elif text_list[i] == 'pulisher':
            for a in range(0, i-1):
                temp.append(text_list[a])
            composer.append(''.join(temp))
            temp.clear()
            for b in range(0, i+1):
            text_list.pop(b)
        break
    i = i +1
return text_list
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get?

Comment: I tried to use split(). But I couldn't recognize creator and publisher's index.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: @wp78de So I edited my question. I don't think stack overflow provides full perfect code instead me. I just want to ask about how can I make a code using regex. Don't get me wrong.

Comment: @eurotrash python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split your array using regex with a capture group, the value that you split on will also be passed into the output array.

You can then loop through looking for `'creator'` or `'publisher'` and in each case, pass the previous entry into the proper collection.

```js
const text = "hellovision hey creator   yoyo  b  creator great  publisher"

const splitArr = text.split(/(creator|publisher)/)

const creators = [], publishers = []

let i = -1, len = splitArr.length

while(++i < len){
  if(splitArr[i] == "creator") creators.push(splitArr[i-1].trim())
  else if(splitArr[i] == "publisher") publishers.push(splitArr[i-1].trim())
}

console.log("creators: ", creators)
console.log("publishers: ", publishers)
```